# Run NodeJS as a Service on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, google-api-nodejs-client

i'm try to run nodejs as service as this steps 
1- `sudo vim servicelocator.conf` 
2- `past this .conf`

```
description "node.js server"
author      "mahmoud elgohary"
# Used to Be: Start on Startup
# until we found some mounts weren't ready yet while booting:
start on started mountall
stop on shutdown

# Automatically Respawn:
respawn
respawn limit 99 5

script
    # Not sure why $HOME is needed, but we found that it is:
    export HOME="/root"

    exec /usr/bin/node /var/lib/nodejsproject/servicelocator/server.js >> /var/log/node.log 2>&1
end script

post-start script
   # Optionally put a script here that will notifiy you node has (re)started
   # /root/bin/hoptoad.sh "node.js has started!"
end script
```

3- `init-checkconf /etc/init/servicelocator.conf`

ERROR: File /etc/init/servicelocator.conf: syntax invalid: init:servicelocator.conf:1: Unknown stanza

4-

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-37-243:/etc/init$ sudo start servicelocator
 start: Unknown job: servicelocator
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this with upstart:

1. Install upstart `sudo apt-get install upstart`
2. Create the .conf file to start you Node.js program `sudo vim /etc/init/servicelocator.conf`
3. Edit the `servicelocator.conf` that you created and insert the text below:

> ```
> #!upstart
> description "servicelocator"
> ```
>
> `start on runlevel [2345] 
>   stop on runlevel [06]`
>
> `#Automatically Respawn: 
>   respawn 
>   respawn limit 99 5`
>
> `exec /usr/bin/node /var/lib/nodejsproject/servicelocator/server.js >>
>   /var/log/node.log`

Save and close the file.

To start the service: `sudo start servicelocator`

Comment: sudo yum install upstart
There are no enabled repos.
 Run "yum repolist all" to see the repos you have.
 You can enable repos with yum-config-manager --enable <repo>

Comment: Try this: `sudo apt-get install upstart` after create the `servicelocator.conf` file then start the service.

Answer (score 0):

my best answer in steps

1- run `sudo vim servicelocator.conf`

2- past this config

```
description "node.js server"
author      "mahmoud elgohary"

#!upstart
description "servicelocator"
start on runlevel [2345] 
stop on runlevel [06]

# Automatically Respawn:
respawn
respawn limit 99 5

script
    # Not sure why $HOME is needed, but we found that it is:
    export HOME="/root"

    exec /usr/bin/nodejs /var/lib/nodejsproject/servicelocator/server.js >> /var/log/node.log 2>&1
end script

post-start script
   # Optionally put a script here that will notifiy you node has (re)started
   # /root/bin/hoptoad.sh "node.js has started!"
end script
```

3- press Esc and wirte `:wq`

5- `sudo apt-get install upstart`

6- `sudo start servicelocator`